# Instrumentation amplifier with capacitor in the feedback network of the first stage

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, low-pass

[image]Instrumentation amplifier with capacitor in the feedback of the first stage. Is this a second order filter or should be analyzed as just first order filter parallel coupled at Rg. Av = 1+2Zf/zg  z2= Rf//C1 Z1 = Rg. Anybody have any idea how to analyze such a circuit?

Comment: Schematic please, I'm not sure where the cap is.

Comment: Its just a first order filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an instrumentation amplifier, it's just a fully differential (input and output) amplifier. It could be the "front half" of an instrumentation amplifier.

The capacitors form a first order filter, as Tony says, with a cutoff angular frequency of \$1\over{R_1 C_1}\$ = \$1\over{R_2 C_2}\$, assuming it's symmetrical.

If you want a second order filter, you can put a differential MFB arrangement around the amplifiers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the MFB arrangement around the amplifier or point me towards a source of knowledge Spehro Pefhany? Much appreciated. Now I have tried a MFB sallen key differential filter. There are papers on how with a resistor network the circuit can maintain a high CMRR. However, when your source is of low resistance impedance. Loading it just cannot be avoided.

Comment: Yes the arrangements I'm familiar with are not High-z input.